# Can we do background update with local notification just like remote notification on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push

I know there are 3 ways of delivering updates to users, remote push notification, background refresh and local notification.
With remote push notification in AppDelegate application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) gets called.

Is there something like that for local notification as well? For example can I get a call back within the app when a local notification is fired and do some updates on the background ? (you get 30 seconds or something with background refresh last I heard)

Comment: No. A local notification is delivered by iOS. Your app only executes if the user taps it.

Comment: I agree. By the way, you have two types of background tasks, background fetch and background processing. Which you use depends upon what your “background update” consists.